# XOR Encryption on Unicode Strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, xor

I'm currently attempting to do some basic XOR encryption on some plain text, but can't seem to get it working. I've found the typical solutions online, but all of them tend to throw errors, and I'm unfortunately not quite familiar with all the byte/encoding stuff yet.

Here is the most common solution I found online:

```
def xor_crypt_string(data, key, encode = False, decode = False):
    if decode:
        data = base64.decodestring(data)
    xored = ''.join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x,y) in zip(data, cycle(key)))
    if encode:
        return base64.encodestring(xored).strip()
    return xored
```

However, when I run it, I get

```
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str
```

I've also tried:

```
key = "mykey"
msg = "this is an example msg"
encrypted = [ chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for (a, b) in zip(msg, cycle(key)) ]
decrypted = [ a ^ b for (a,b) in zip(bytes(encrypted)) ]
```

The encryption stage seems to work great, but when decrypting I get hit with a

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I just can't seem to get these solutions to work for me, and am wondering what the case is. For further information, my `data` and `key` are simply plain text.

This is a complete guess, but what might be throwing it off is that my `data` might be formatted or encoded weirdly? My `data` sometimes will be blank, and sometimes will include emojis (so Unicode I think?) if that matters at all. My encryption input is essentially any character / format you can think of.

To clarify, I'm using Python 3.

**Update:**

Other attempts:

When encoding the string prior to encrypting, such as

```
xor_crypt_string(data.encode('utf-8'), key, encode=True)
```

It then complains about the `ord` casting. I then tried removing the casting, but realized the key is still a string, and wasn't able to resolve how to deal with this discrepency. I.e. when,

```
''.join(chr(x ^ ord(y)) for (x,y) in zip(data, cycle(key)))

Error:
unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'int' and 'str'
```

```
''.join(chr(x ^ y) for (x,y) in zip(data, cycle(key)))

Error:
expected bytes-like object, not str
```

**Second Update:**

I got it kinda working with this version of the function:

```
def xor_crypt_string(data, key, encode = False, decode = False):
    if decode:
        data = base64.decodestring(data)
    xored = ''.join(chr(x ^ y) for (x,y) in zip(data, cycle(key)))
    if encode:
        # return base64.encodestring(xored).strip()
        return base64.encodestring(xored.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '').strip()
    return xored
```

However, it does not work consistently. Take for example,

```
// Works great!
before: sounds like ur suppressing ur own creativity
encrypted: EhwRCAASUwgPChZEExNTFxMUEQEBFRIaCgFBBhZGCxYdRAUTFgUSCAUNEh0=
after: sounds like ur suppressing ur own creativity

// Breaks...
before: disliked “wasn’t trolling!!! just agreeing that kaf’s buns can’t compare!!!”
encrypted: BRoXCg0KFgBGwoPDs8O4EQAACsKEw6TDuAdEEhMcCAoIHQNHRUBTDhMSB0QHBgEBAw0PFEQSCRIQRgoSAsKEw6TDuABEBBQdF0YCEgrChMOkw7gHRAUOHhQHExZFR0XCg8Ozw7k=
after: disliked £ð§Õ¢Ëufdk±à¥Å°Üa%awzlk{ye&6$5o`va fuegb~kr%amtt'yvd£÷§Â¢Ëd"`uns can¤å°À¥Üf7ahgcuw6##¦â°×¥Ø

before: lol i didn’t post it, waiting for the right context
encrypted: DRwIRg1BFw0CD8KRw6TDvxVTFAkXFVMNEk1TEwcIBw0IA0EVCxRBBwwDQQENAQwVUwcJDwcBHhU=
after: lol i didn±õ¥Å°Ûs7uzss2~v+2`cncl{g'txp'fg'elrhs2tmifrzs
```

I'm guessing that certain characters are breaking it - it looks like the non-standard quotations are messing things up.

Comment: before encoding, convert your string to bytes with something like `data.encode('utf-8')`. When reverting the process use `decode` to get a unicode string from utf-8 bytes.

Comment: @PauloScardine unfortunately also tried that, will update original post with this case

Comment: You probably want to use `bytes(...)` instead of `''.join(...)`.

Comment: I think the bug is encoding the cyphertext again as utf-8 in `xored.encode('utf-8')` - cyphertext is supposed to be utf-8 bytes already.